# How to convert date format before comparison in YII?

Tags: php, yii, date-conversion, date-comparison

I am using the default search provided by the YII CGridView.
I have a text date field in the search criteria. I am trying to compare the date passed with the date in the database but they are not matching. I need to convert the format of the dates stored in the database as the date in the database also have time and I need to remove time before comparing the dates, But I cannot figure out a way to do this.

In the default Search function() this is the line where I want to convert the dates before comparing. I have tried the conversion but this does not seem to work.

```
$criteria->compare(date("Y-m-d", strtotime('application_date')),
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->application_date)),true);
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: did you try formatting the date within this statement

Comment: Yes I tried but it I can only format the date I am passing, not the date in the database. I need to format the date I get from the database before comparing it.

Comment: Why not format the input date to the database format?

Comment: actually database base date has time and while comparing I want to exclude the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one way of doing this, You have to use Date_Format function of mysql like follow:

```
$criteria->compare('DATE_FORMAT(application_date,"%Y-%m-%d")',date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->application_date)),true);
```

Comment: Good answer! Thank you. It's possible to use comparison operator for greater than...
For example: ```$criteria->compare('DATE_FORMAT(application_date,"%Y-%m-%d")',date("Y-m-d", '>='.strtotime($this->application_date)),true);```

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the date to date in the the database  as ex to your desired format shown below

```
 $criteria->compare('date1',date("d-m-Y",strtotime($this->date1),true);
```

Comment: actually database base date has time and while comparing I want to exclude the time part.

Comment: ya that only you convert the date which u entered to the format of database entry and compare